# How to correctly set the dateElementOrder in datejs to use partial dates

Tags: jquery, datejs

In [datejs](http://groups.google.com/group/datejs), if i set the dateElementOrder to the pt-PT localized version of "dmy" or "ymd" instead of "mdy" the following tests on the "Partial" test fixture start to fail:

1/2008; 1 2008; 1-2008; 2008/1; 2008 1; 2008-1

What do i need to do to make it work?

Comment: cross-posted in the datejs group (so far no answers): http://groups.google.com/group/datejs/browse_thread/thread/a22314de997450b9/ff7fd4bb27ac3657

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with what you are using, but is it defined as literally "dmy" instead of "mdy"? I would imagine you would differentiate between days and months, perhaps by making sure that months are listed as 01, 02, 03, etc..., where as days would just be single digits for single digit days?

It might be a bug, have you posted the issue to their [Issues](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/list) page? Double-check all your syntax before you do so, just to make sure it's not a simple mistake somewhere along the line. Javascript can get messy.